# MySQL SELECT SUM CASE with GROUP BY or DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case, distinct

I'm trying to count unique user ids in a log table by month. So far I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN log_date LIKE '2020-01%' THEN 1 END) AS januari
FROM user_log;
```

This query returns the total of all rows of the user_log in januari. However I would like to know how many **unique** users have logged in in Januari. So I need something like:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(**DISTINCT user_id** CASE WHEN log_date LIKE '2020-01%' THEN 1 END) AS januari
FROM user_log;
```

I also tried GROUP BY, but so far no luck. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Testing the date using string context is bad practice. Use `log_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'` - this allows to use index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN log_date >= '2020-01-01' AND log_date < '2020-02-01' THEN userid END) AS januari
FROM user_log;
```

I changed the filtering logic to use half-open intervals rather than string matching: it is more efficient.

Note that, if you just that result for January, it is sufficient to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) januari
FROM user_log
WHERE log_date >= '2020-01-01' AND log_date < '2020-02-01'
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB. Your answer works fine. I do need the other months too so the first option is the one  I used.